# After Effect Values depend on between x,y position

Tags: after-effects

By using expression

How to react values depending on (x,y) both position at same time

I tried to changing color depend on shape moving (x,Y) but not working ;(

I did it only in X position

```
var Black = [0,0,0,255]/255;
var White = [255,255,255,255]/255;
if(thisComp.layer("Select Color").transform.xPosition <96){
    Black
}
}    
else{White}`
```